# CSS: Bootstrap - sticky-footer wrong position with mobile browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 - for this topic especiall the sticky-footer makes problems on mobile phones and devices (e.g. Chrome @ Samsung Galaxy 4, IPad).

I'm using a div container (wrap_con) to push the footer down to the end of the page. So my html code looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap_con"> 
page content
</div>
<div id="my_footer">

two container (<div class="container">) are implementing the footer here

</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap 3 with following own extensions:

```
#wrap_con { 
background-color:white; 
font-color:black;
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
border: 0px solid white;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto -150px;  
/* margin: 0 auto 0px; */ 
min-height: 100%;
padding: 0 0 150px;  
/* padding: 0 0 0px;  */
}


 #my_footer {
 height: 150px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 10px;
 border: 0px solid white;
 border-style: none;
 }


#my_footer .container:first-of-type {
 background: transparent url(footer_bg_white.gif) repeat;
 width: 100%;
 border: 0px solid white;
 height: 80px;
 padding-top: -30px;
 }

 #my_footer .container:last-of-type {
 background: transparent url(footer_bg.gif) repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 border: 0px solid white;
 }
```

So in praxis two container should always stick on bottom of the page and implement the footer. This works great in all desktop browsers but if it comes to view the site on a mobile browser the footer is not on the bottom of the page. There is a distance of about 75px between the footer and the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your footer, on a media-query for mobile.

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

Did you try it? @joe